# C# number guessing game

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple number guessing game in C#. The program generates a random number when you click the "Generate random number" button. Once you enter your guess in the textbox and click "Guess", the program lets you know if you've guessed right or wrong.

The problem is that I can't pass the randomly generated number to myFunction() so it can validate the user's guess. Here's the code and it's a bit of a mess; and thank you all in advance for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Number_guessing_game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        int montH;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            myFunction(int montH);      
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int montH = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        }

        void myFunction(int montH)
        {
            int guess = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            if (guess == montH)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You win!");
            }

            if (guess != montH)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You lose!");
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `button2_Click` function. Inside the function after you generate a random number, you are creating a new int and assigning the random number to that, instead of the already declared class-level variable. Change your `button2_Click` to the following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    montH = new Random().Next(1,10);
}
```

Another few things I will mention, because montH is a class-level variable, it is accessible by every function in your class, so you don't need to pass it as a parameter to `myFunction()`, in fact, `button1_Click` could validate the result for you:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.Parse(TextBox1.Text) == montH)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Win!!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Lose...");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use `int.TryParse`, in case the user enters a non-number character.

Comment: spot on my friend. I was indeed unintentionally declaring 2 variables but still treating them as one and expecting them to work. This solved my problem neatly. Now I can add counters to give the player 3 guesses and even keep score. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Simply define your `montH` as a class level variable(as you did), then use following code:

```
int montH;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Random rnd = new Random();
   montH = rnd.Next(1, 10);  //<--- there is no need to redefine montH by int monthH
}
private void GussButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myFunction(month);
}
```

If in your `button2_click` event handler want to use it there isn't need to redefine it by `int montH;`,
because `int montH;` cause define a new `montH` variable in method level.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    montH = rnd.Next(1, 10);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below works for you ! What you dont need to do is actually put your montH in your Function itself since it is a seen variable to the class. When you are comparing the guess ==montH it is already taking the montH int assigned and checking from your montH variable.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace Number_guessing_game
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int montH;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myFunction();      
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int montH = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        }

        void myFunction()
        {
            int guess = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            if (guess == montH)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("You win!");
            }

            if (guess != montH)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You lose!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
namespace Number_guessing_game
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public int montH;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myFunction(montH);      





    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         montH=0;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    montH = rnd.Next(1, 10);



    }


    void myFunction(montH)
    {
        int guess = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (guess == montH)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You win!");
        }

        if (guess != montH)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You lose!");
        }




    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new montH in button2_Click()... otherwise the new montH only alive in this function

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    montH = rnd.Next(1, 10);



    }
```